# Unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)- WIndows 10- python 3.9.6

Tags: python

Good morning everyone.
Trying to read an email from imap I encounter the error that I attach.

` File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
self.do_handshake()

File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()

ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)`

Many people say that this problem can be solved by doing:

1. pip install certifi
2. pip install --upgrade certifi

I have done both, but I keep getting the same error.

Thank you very much for your collaboration

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please format your answers using the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting